# Bind search results in kendoGrid MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I need help here.I have kendogrid, which need to have a popup.Popup is loading from template(view1.cshtml) and everything is working perfectly.But when i add search in my page, and than add following code

```
                          type: "json",
                   transport: {
                       read: {
                           url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ListFinances", "Jobs"))",
                           type: "POST",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: additionalData
                       },

                   },
                   schema: {
                       data: "Data",
                       total: "Total",
                       errors: "Errors"
                   },
```

in rest of the code in grid(search results are bind here to grid),search is working, popup is not working nothing and is showing when i click on the button to show up popup.What is here wrong?Thanks

```
                    <script>
                     $(function() {
                        $("#jobs-grid").kendoGrid({
                            dataSource: {
                                data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FinishedJobs)),
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        fields: {
                                            JobNumber: { type: "string" },
                                            CustomerId: { type: "number" },
                                            JobCount: { type: "number" },
                                            JobYear: { type: "number" },
                                            Status: { type: "number" },
                                            Position: { type: "number" },
                                            Finished: { type: "boolean" },
                                            HasInvoice: { type: "boolean" },
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                @*type: "json",
                   transport: {
                       read: {
                           url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ListFinances", "Jobs"))",
                           type: "POST",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: additionalData
                       },

                   },
                   schema: {
                       data: "Data",
                       total: "Total",
                       errors: "Errors"
                   },*@
                                error: function(e) {
                                    display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                    // Cancel the changes
                                    this.cancelChanges();
                                },

                                pageSize: 20,
                                serverPaging: true,
                                serverFiltering: true,
                                serverSorting: true,

                            },

                            //dataBound: onDataBound,
                            columns: [
                                @*{
                                            field: "Status",
                                            title: "@T("gp.Jobs.Fields.Status")",
                                            template: '#= Status #'
                                        },*@
                                {
                                    field: "JobNumber",
                                    title: "@T("gp.Job.Fields.JobNumber")",
                                    template: '#= JobNumber #'
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "CustomerId",
                                    title: "@T("gp.Job.Fields.Customer")",
                                    template: '#= Customer.Name #'
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "Id",
                                    title: "@T("gp.Job.Fields.Name")"
                                },

                                @*{
                                            field: "ShortDesc",
                                            title: "@T("gp.Jobs.Fields.ShortDesc")"
                                        },*@
                                {
                                    field: "DateCompletition",
                                    title: "@T("gp.Job.Fields.DateCompletition")"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "Id",
                                    title: "@T("Common.Edit")",
                                    width: 130,
                                    template: '<a href="Edit/#=Id#">@T("Common.Edit")</a>'
                                }
                            ],
                            pageable: {
                                refresh: true,
                                pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50]
                            },
                            editable: {
                                confirmation: false,
                                mode: "inline"
                            },
                            scrollable: false,

                            //  sortable: true,
                            //  navigatable: true,
                            //   filterable: true,
                            //  scrollable: true,
                            selectable: true,

        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#jobRowTemplate").html()),

                        });

        </script>
```

Comment: popup is inside grid or there is one cell inside grid after clicking it is showing pop-up or grid is inside pop-up?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane from last column  {
                                    field: "Id",
                                    title: "@T("Common.Edit")",
                                    width: 130,
                                    template: '<a href="Edit/#=Id#">@T("Common.Edit")</a>'
                                } popup is loading

Comment: @KalpeshDusane rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#jobRowTemplate").html()), this is script which is loading from    @Html.Partial("_jobRowTemplate")

Comment: After Adding Search functionality But before applying search on grid is Pop-up is loading?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane Yeah, but i found a solution, i will write it later